# how to redirect to page by clicking on button having these conditions

Tags: visualforce, javascript

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/32.0/connection.js")}
var Stage = "{!Opportunity.StageName}"; 
var oppId = "{!Opportunity.Id}"; 
var userId = "{!$User.Id}";

var result = 
sforce.connection.query(
    "SELECT Id " +
    "FROM PermissionSetAssignment " +
    "WHERE PermissionSetId = '0PS1g0000008OiJ' " +
    "AND AssigneeId ='{!$User.Id}'" 
);

var psAssignment = result.getArray("records");

//alert("psAssignment :"+psAssignment);
if(Stage != 'Signed LOI' )
{
  alert('Stage is not Signed LOI'); 
  window.location.reload(); 

} 
else if(psAssignment.length == 0 && "{!$Profile.Name}" != 'System 
Administrator')
{
    alert('You do not have permissions to manage portal access'); 
    window.location.reload(); 

}
else if(Stage != 'Signed LOI' && (psAssignment.length == 0 && "
{!$Profile.Name}" != 'System Administrator'))
{
   alert('You do not have permissions to manage portal access and 
   Opportunity is not Signed LOI'); 
   window.location.reload(); 

}  
else{ 
   window.location = "apex/EOBGrantPortalVF?oppId="+oppId; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it is not totally clear as of what you are trying to ask here. As per what I understood, you will need to create a new custom button from Setup>Object>Button,LinksandActions>New and add the mentioned code to that button.

Last step would be to place the button on the object's layout, which in your case here is Opportunity.
Does this makes sense? Please clarify if you are asking something else here.

Edit 1:

Javascript code for the button will be as follows:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/apex.js")} 

//Note here, that test1 is Custom Permission(see help pages)

//**Help page1:** https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custom_perms_overview.htm&type=0 , 
//**Help page2:**  https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=perm_sets_custom_perms.htm&type=5).

if({!$Permission.test1} && "{!$Profile.Name}" == 'System Administrator')
{
    var testField="{!Opportunity.StageName}";
    if(testField !=null && testField == 'Signed LOI')
    {
       alert('filled'); //Can put the desired data or page where we need redirection to.
    }
    else
    {
       alert('empty');
    }
}
else
{  
    alert('You do not have permissions to manage portal access');  
}
```

Comment: yes sir i want the same thing but  i need code  for

Comment: • CONDITION 1:Button should work only for users with permission set “EOB Manager” or  profile System Admins. IF any other user tries to access throw readable error on top of that Opportunity Page show ERROR: “You do not have permissions to manage portal access”.
• CONDITION 2:Button should work only when Stage (API Name: StageName) is Signed LOI. If any other stage other than Signed LOI throw ERROR “Opportunity is not Signed LOI”.
• When Stage (API Name: StageName) is not Signed LOI  then throw error “ Opportunity is not Signed LOI”.

Comment: @SunilChandel Have updated the original comment, please see above and try it over the button. Let me know if it works well.

Comment: Thanks @SunilChandel Please do give credit/vote to the comment so that others can be helped with the answer in case they face the similar issue.